# Merge given field value of all rows in one and send in json array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am facing a problem.

My table contain a field named 'tags'.

This field have comma separated values.

**For ex:** Hello, start, good & another one is: Time, Goal, Lucky, start.

Now my problem is that, I want to send each comma separated values in json array 
and none of them should repeat itself.
My array should be like this:

**{
"tag":[
"Hello",
"start",
"good",
"Time",
"Goal",
"Lucky"
]
}**

Comment: Now I think you might understand why storing data in a comma seperated list in a single column is such a bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this with your code.

Assuming `$tag_string` has the comma separated data.

```
<?php
$tag_string= "Hello, start, good, Time, Goal, Lucky, start";
$val['tag'] = explode(",", $tag_string);
$val['tag'] = array_unique($val['tag']);
echo json_encode($val);
?>
```

As you asked in comment answer::

```
<?php
$tag_string = "Hello, start, good, Time, Goal, Lucky, start";
$val = explode(",", $tag_string);
$val_count = count($val);$html = "[ ";$counter = 1;$data_validate = [];
foreach ($val as $val_row)
{
    if (!in_array($val_row, $data_validate))
    {
        $data_validate[] = $val_row;
        $html .= '{"tag":"' . $val_row . '"}';
        $html .= $counter < $val_count-1 ? ',' : '';
    }
    $counter ++;
}
$html .= " ]";
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: @nehachaukikar Please accept the answer if it helped you and for others.

Comment: i need one more help @Rana :: What if i want to get the array into individual object.. i mean like this:                                                                               [
{
"tag":"Hello"
},

{
"tag":"start"
},

{
"tag":"good"
},
{
"tag":"Time"
},
{
"tag":"Goal"
},
{
"tag":"Lucky"
}
]

Comment: @nehachaukikar did you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp to make à php array then just use jdon_encode() on your array.

You can also use php explose() function to make your php array.

Comment: thank you @Sphinx for your response but can you elaborate a little more please..

Comment: See the answer of rana ghost. But if you want you can read the doc of the function I am talking about and you Will find à solution fast ! I think you should, that is the best way to improve your skills! Your problem is really easy to solve! That's why i dont like to give the full solution. I try to help you for improve your skills. Ask for a solution about this kind of problems is not a good way to learn.

Comment: Thank You @Sphinx, I will definitely work on it.

Answer (score 0):

use *json_encode(explode(', ', "Hello", "start", "good", "Time", "Goal", "Lucky"));*

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have space in your string.
split String using delimiter "," using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and remove duplicate value [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

```
  $your_str = "Hello,start,good,Time,Goal,Lucky"
    $res["tag"] = array_unique(explode(",", $your_str));
    print_r(json_encode($res));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$tag_string= "Hello, start, good, Time, Goal, Lucky, start";
$result = [];
$result['tag'] = array_unique(preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $tag_string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
echo json_encode($result);
```